# alternate way to proceed without list in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scala code like this

```
 def avgCalc(buffer: Iterable[Array[String]], list: Array[String]) = {
    val currentTimeStamp = list(1).toLong // loads the timestamp column
    var sum = 0.0
    var count = 0
    var check = false
    import scala.util.control.Breaks._
    breakable {
      for (array <- buffer) {
        val toCheckTimeStamp = array(1).toLong // timestamp column
        if (((currentTimeStamp - 10L) <= toCheckTimeStamp) && (currentTimeStamp >= toCheckTimeStamp)) { // to check the timestamp for 10 seconds difference
          sum += array(5).toDouble // RSSI weightage values
          count += 1
        }

        if ((currentTimeStamp - 10L) > toCheckTimeStamp) {

          check = true
          break

        }
      }
    }
     list :+ sum

  }
```

I will call the above function like this

```
 import spark.implicits._
  val averageDF =
    filterop.rdd.map(_.mkString(",")).map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim))
      .sortBy(array => array(1), false) // Sort by timestamp
      .groupBy(array => (array(0), array(2))) // group by tag and listner
      .mapValues(buffer => {
        buffer.map(list => {
         avgCalc(buffer, list) // calling the average function 
        })
      })
      .flatMap(x => x._2)
      .map(x => findingavg(x(0).toString, x(1).toString.toLong, x(2).toString, x(3).toString, x(4).toString, x(5).toString.toDouble, x(6).toString.toDouble)) // defining the schema through case class
      .toDF // converting to data frame
```

The above code is working fine.But I need to get rid of list.My senior ask me to remove the list,Because list reduces the execution speed.Any suggestions to proceed without list ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: All of `_.mkString(",")).map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim)` seems like a no-op... If you are going to make a string, then split it, you get back the initial collection

Comment: That one I am calling my initial data frame.

Comment: Well, which list are you trying to get rid of? If you have an `RDD[Array]`, then how are you supposed to get rid of that?

Comment: list: Array[String]) .this list i want to get rid off

Comment: I tried like this val currentTimeStamp = Array(1).. But it throws error in timestamp valuation.Int to long error

Comment: You are using the `list` twice. First when you are doing an index based lookup to get the timestamp `list(1).toLong` and second is when you are appending to it `list:+sum` both of which have a time complexity of O(n) which isn't that bad. You can try scala `Queue` which should provide you a O(1) whenever you append to it.

Comment: that array (list) is needed for the update of average value. Do you want to avoid it from using as an argument to avgCalc function? or you want to avoid it fully?

Comment: Instead of list iteration I need to pass & evaluate the output directly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following solution should work I guess, I have tried to avoid passing both iterable and one array.

```
def avgCalc(buffer: Iterable[Array[String]]) = {
  var finalArray = Array.empty[Array[String]]
  import scala.util.control.Breaks._
  breakable {
    for (outerArray <- buffer) {
      val currentTimeStamp = outerArray(1).toLong
      var sum = 0.0
      var count = 0
      var check = false
      var list = outerArray
      for (array <- buffer) {
        val toCheckTimeStamp = array(1).toLong
        if (((currentTimeStamp - 10L) <= toCheckTimeStamp) && (currentTimeStamp >= toCheckTimeStamp)) {
          sum += array(5).toDouble
          count += 1
        }
        if ((currentTimeStamp - 10L) > toCheckTimeStamp) {
          check = true
          break
        }
      }
      if (sum != 0.0 && check) list = list :+ (sum / count).toString
      else list = list :+ list(5).toDouble.toString

      finalArray ++= Array(list)
    }
  }
  finalArray
}
```

and you can call it like

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val averageDF =
  filter_op.rdd.map(_.mkString(",")).map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim))
    .sortBy(array => array(1), false)
    .groupBy(array => (array(0), array(2)))
    .mapValues(buffer => {
        avgCalc(buffer)
    })
    .flatMap(x => x._2)
    .map(x => findingavg(x(0).toString, x(1).toString.toLong, x(2).toString, x(3).toString, x(4).toString, x(5).toString.toDouble, x(6).toString.toDouble))
    .toDF
```

I hope this is the desired answer

Comment: Perfect Solution !

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you have accepted an answer, but I have to say that you have a lot of unnecessary code. As far as I can see, you have no reason to do the initial conversion to `Array` type in the first place and the `sortBy` is also unnecessary at this point. I would suggest you work directly on the `Row`.

Also you have a number of unused variables that should be removed and converting to a case-class only to be followed by a `toDF` seems excessive IMHO.

I would do something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

def avgCalc(sortedList: List[Row]) = {
  sortedList.indices.map(i =>  {
    var sum = 0.0
    val row = sortedList(i)
    val currentTimeStamp = row.getString(1).toLong // loads the timestamp column

    import scala.util.control.Breaks._
    breakable {
      for (j <- 0 until sortedList.length) {
        if (j != i) {
          val anotherRow = sortedList(j)
          val toCheckTimeStamp = anotherRow.getString(1).toLong // timestamp column
          if (((currentTimeStamp - 10L) <= toCheckTimeStamp) && (currentTimeStamp >= toCheckTimeStamp)) { // to check the timestamp for 10 seconds difference
            sum += anotherRow.getString(5).toDouble // RSSI weightage values
          }

          if ((currentTimeStamp - 10L) > toCheckTimeStamp) {
            break
          }
        }
      }
    }
    (row.getString(0), row.getString(1), row.getString(2), row.getString(3), row.getString(4), row.getString(5), sum.toString)
  })
}


val averageDF = filterop.rdd
  .groupBy(row => (row(0), row(2)))
  .flatMap{case(_,buffer) => avgCalc(buffer.toList.sortBy(_.getString(1).toLong))}
  .toDF("Tag", "Timestamp", "Listner", "X", "Y", "RSSI", "AvgCalc")
```

And as a final comment, I'm pretty sure it's possible to come up with at nicer/cleaner implementation of the `avgCalc` function, but I'll leave it to you to play around with that :)